# Infinite loop on login redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, infinite-loop

I have a login script which generally works for me, but occasionally goes into an infinite loop on redirecting after checking the cookie stored for login. The browser will report something like the following: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."  Others have reported this issue too.  Below are the key elements of the login process.  I wonder if someone can see what the issue is with this process/script.

Thanks,

Nick

First at the **top of each page** that is protected:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

require('login/config.php');
require('login/functions.php'); 

if (allow_access(Users) != "yes")
{ 
include ('login/check_login.php'); 
exit;
}
?>
```

Then in **check_login.php**:

```
<?
session_start();

//check to see if the user already has an open session
if (($_SESSION[user_name] != "") && ($_SESSION[password] != ""))
{

    header("Location:$_SESSION[redirect]");
    exit;
}

$lr_user = $_COOKIE['lr_user'];
$lr_pass = $_COOKIE['lr_pass'];

//check to see if cookies have been set previously
if(($lr_user != "") && ($lr_pass != ""))
{
    header("Location:/login/redirect.php");
    exit;
}

//if neither is true, redirect to login
    header("Location:/login/login.php");

?>
```

Then, in **redirect.php:**

```
<?
session_start();

//require the functions file
require ("config.php");
require ("functions.php");

$lr_user = $_COOKIE['lr_user'];
$lr_pass = $_COOKIE['lr_pass'];

//check to see if cookies are already set, remember me
if ((!$lr_user) || (!$lr_pass))
{

$username = $_POST[username];
$password = $_POST[password];

}else{

$username = $lr_user;
$password = $lr_pass;

}

//sets cookies to remember this computer if the user asks to
if ($_POST[remember] == "Yes")
{
setcookie("lr_user", $username, $duration, "/", $domain);
setcookie("lr_pass", $password, $duration, "/", $domain);
}

//sets session variables
sess_vars($base_dir, $server, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db_name, $table_name, $username, $password);

if(isset($_SESSION['url']))
  $_SESSION[redirect] = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
   $_SESSION[redirect] = "/index.php"; // default page for

//redirects the user    
header("Location:$_SESSION[redirect]");
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

//function to get the date
function last_login()
{
    $date = gmdate("Y-m-d");
    return $date;
}

//function that sets the session variable
function sess_vars($base_dir, $server, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db_name, $table_name, $username, $password)
{

    //make connection to dbase
    $connection = @mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword)
                or die(mysql_error());

    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection)
                or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE username = '$username' and password = password('$password')";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());


    //get the number of rows in the result set
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //set session variables if there is a match
    if ($num != 0) 
    {
        while ($sql = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
        {
            $_SESSION[first_name]   = $sql -> firstname;
            $_SESSION[last_name]    = $sql -> lastname; 
            $_SESSION[user_name]    = $sql -> username;       
            $_SESSION[password]     = $sql -> password;
            $_SESSION[group1]       = $sql -> group1;
            $_SESSION[group2]       = $sql -> group2;
            $_SESSION[group3]       = $sql -> group3;
            $_SESSION[pchange]      = $sql -> pchange;  
            $_SESSION[email]        = $sql -> email;
            $_SESSION[redirect]     = $sql -> redirect;
            $_SESSION[verified]     = $sql -> verified;
            $_SESSION[last_login]   = $sql -> last_login;
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION[redirect] = "$base_dir/errorlogin.php";
    }
}


//functions that will determine if access is allowed
function allow_access($group)
{
    if ($_SESSION[group1] == "$group" || $_SESSION[group2] == "$group" || $_SESSION[group3] == "$group" ||
        $_SESSION[group1] == "Administrators" || $_SESSION[group2] == "Administrators" || $_SESSION[group3] == "Administrators" ||
        $_SESSION[user_name] == "$group")
        {
            $allowed = "yes";
        }else{
            $allowed = "no";
        }
    return $allowed;
}

//function to check the length of the requested password
function password_check($min_pass, $max_pass, $pass)
{

    $valid = "yes";
    if ($min_pass > strlen($pass) || $max_pass < strlen($pass))
    {
        $valid = "no";
    }

    return $valid;
}

?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?

//set up the names of the database and table
$db_name ="";
$table_name ="authorize";

//connect to the server and select the database
$server = "localhost";
$dbusername = "";
$dbpassword = "*";

//domain information
$domain = "";

//Change to "0" to turn off the login log
$log_login = "1";

//base_dir is the location of the files, ie http://www.yourdomain/login
$base_dir = "";

//length of time the cookie is good for - 7 is the days and 24 is the hours
//if you would like the time to be short, say 1 hour, change to 60*60*1
$duration = time()+60*60*24*365*10;

//the site administrator\'s email address
$adminemail = "";

//sets the time to EST
$zone=3600*00;

//do you want the verify the new user through email if the user registers themselves?
//yes = "0" :  no = "1"
$verify = "0";

//default redirect, this is the URL that all self-registered users will be redirected to
$default_url = "";

//minimum and maximum password lengths
$min_pass = 8;
$max_pass = 15;


$num_groups = 0+2;
$group_array = array("Users","Administrators");

?>
```

Comment: hmm, I assume the variables like $_SESSION[redirect], $_POST[remember], et al are just missed typed and are really $_SESSION['redirect']  and $_POST['remember']? if not they should be. Security wise you should really address the use of storing a password in a cookie (no need to) and validating your $_POST data (and $_SESSION for that matter). My initial guess with your loop is your $_SESSION['url'] and $_SESSION[redirect] and not set correctly. Is there any further info to exactly when it happens (i.e have they previously logged in, returned and then it happens?) / have you reproduced it?

Comment: Where does your $_SESSION['url'] come from, as this may be set in the wrong place / before the other checks which could enable an already logged in user to get the $_SESSION['url'] set to something like the check_login.php which would cause a loop.

Comment: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) for God's sake!

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I think that it may well be that the issue is happening for users who are already logged in. The two people who have reported this issue would have previously been logged in. The $SESSION['url'] is set at the top of each protected page, so that may well be the issue. I have included it in my above code now. Sorry, it should have been there from the start. I'm not sure where I should include it. At the end of the script at the top of each protected page?

Comment: Also I was told by one user that enabling private browsing sorted the issue, which would suggest that it is cookie related.

Comment: @Nick, I updated the answer, I think I found the problem with a assumption about the content of your /login/login.php

Comment: @Nick, please see my updated answer which I believe should work as you require.

Comment: @Nick Is your index.php one of the files that is protected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT - try this:**

I think the problem is that I assume you are trying to protect 'all' pages which also include the index.php. However you have included the index.php as a page in the $_SESSION[redirect] variable. You should think along the lines of:

1. User trys to access a page
2. You should check if they are allowed to
3. If they are allowed to, just let them view the page without interruption
4. If they are not (i.e not logged in) - redirect them to your login page

Your script is trying to still redirect them even if they are allowed to view the page (which is causing the loop problem).

It is a subtle difference, but an important one (especially as you are protecting all pages).

### I would try this:

At the top of your protected pages change the bottom snippet to:

```
if (allow_access(Users) != "yes")
{ 
    include ('login/check_login.php'); 
    check_redirect();
}
```

**In your check_login.php try this:**

```
<?
session_start();

function check_redirect()
{

    //check to see if the user already has an open session
    if (($_SESSION[user_name] != "") && ($_SESSION[password] != ""))
    {
       // just return if they are a valid user (no need to redirect them)
       return;
    }

    $lr_user = $_COOKIE['lr_user'];
    $lr_pass = $_COOKIE['lr_pass'];

    //check to see if cookies have been set previously
    if(($lr_user != "") && ($lr_pass != ""))
    {
       // just return if they are a valid user (no need to redirect them)
       return;
    }

    //if neither is true, redirect to login
    header("Location:/login/login.php");
    die();

}  
?>
```

Your redirect.php is not needed for soley protecting your pages, I assume you use this with your actual login.php script, therefore:

```
$_SESSION['url']
```

Would have stored the page they were trying to get to, and your redirect.php / login.php script should just use this to redirect them back there after successful login.

Lastly the above is untested code but should work better than what you had, let me know how you get on.

---

To be honest it is quite hard to determine exactly what is wrong with your code because there are still a few unknown variables, such as the config and functions files and the function:

```
if (allow_access(Users) != "yes")
```

Which I assume Users should be 'Users', likewise unless it was just loosely typed for this question all the variables which you have like $_SESSION[user_name] you MUST make sure you correctly add the apostrophes or you will get notices all over the place (undefined variable, assumed...etc etc) not too mention this could mess up your session data.

Perhaps if I offered some advice on your current code, you may be able to try some things which could fix your code.

### Multiple redirects / Scripts

I would firstly rewrite your check_login.php and redirect.php scripts - the fact that you have two separate scripts (which could be combined) will always give you problems at some stage, because essentially you are redirecting to a redirect (which isn't logically when you say it out a loud). So firstly rewrite your scripts to one 'auth.php' script. And also simplify your include for pages that require authentication, for example:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // use require_once for your login scripts, not 'include' as you want an error to 
    // occur to halt the page processing if the file is not found, include will just
    // give a warning but still continue with the page processing (which you're trying
    // to protect). Lastly '_once' so you don't get multiple inclusions of the same
    // script by accident (which is always import for login / redirect scripts). 
    require_once('login/auth.php');

    // just create one function which will proxy all the other functions / includes
    // you could exclude this function and just use the require_once file for direct 
    // access - but I would say including a function will make it easier to understand.
    check_login();
?>
```

**Now the auth.php file:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // if these are required use the _once. I would guess some of these 'functions'
    // may be able to be included within this 'auth.php' file directly?
    require_once('login/config.php');
    require_once('login/functions.php'); 

    // set your variables here
    $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // the main check login function
    function check_login() 
    {

        // Check if your user is logged in / needs to be logged in
        // perhaps something from your allow_access() function?

        // Do all the checks for session / cookie you should resolve the checks to
        // a simple bool variable (i.e. if the user is valid or not)
        $userIsValid = true || false; // get this from above code

        // Then use the redirect function and pass in the $userIsValid variable
        // which will tell the redirect() function where to redirect to.
        redirect($userIsValid);

    }

    // use a separate function for the redirect to keep it cleaner 
    // not too sure on all the Url's you have floating around in your code as I
    // would think you either want to let them to proceed to the page they were
    // trying to view (if validated) or you want them to login?      
    function redirect($validUser = false)
    {
        // if the user is valid, just return as you don't have to redirect them
        if ( $validUser ) {
            return true;
        }
        // otherwise just redirect them to the login page
        header("Location:/login/login.php");
        die();
    }

?>
```

## Security

You don't need to (and shouldn't!) be storing the actual password in a session, and I would certainly advice against a cookie also. However if you must store the password / username in a cookie, at the very least you must encrypt it using md5() with a salt, etc. So in a nutshell rather than checking $_SESSION['user_name'] and $_SESSION['password'] it could just be something like:

```
// if the user has no valid session do something:
if ( !isset($_SESSION['id']) ) {


}
```

### Separation of concerns

I'm not sure why your have:

```
$username = $_POST[username];
$password = $_POST[password];
```

Within your redirect.php file, are you also using this script for when users login? I don't think it's a good idea if you are (which may be the problem). You should have a separate script to handle all actual login functionality (including the redirect after logging in). The above should only be concerned with a) checking if the user is valid / logged in b) redirecting them if not - essentially protecting your web page(s).

**Your Code:**

```
//check to see if the user already has an open session
if (($_SESSION[user_name] != "") && ($_SESSION[password] != ""))
{

    header("Location:$_SESSION[redirect]");
    exit;
}
```

I'm not sure I get this bit in the context, as your basically redirecting them if they have a valid session? Scratch that I don't really understand the whole check_login.php script, as things are a bit backwards (especially when combined with your redirect.php script). You are checking the same variables again ($lr_user) || (!$lr_pass) in your redirect script and making reference to things that have not even been set in your check_login.php script.

**EDIT: Could be solution?** 
Unless I have over looked something the above code block makes reference to $_SESSION['redirect'], I think that should be either $_SESSION['url'] or just don't redirect them. The $_SESSION['redirect'] doesn't get set until the redirect.php script (which may not get called if the session exists).

### Final thoughts:

Sorry if this doesn't really answer your question as you would have liked but I really think this would be a good opportunity to take a good look at your script(s) and clean / simplify them. Ideally you should look at this with an OOP approach, i.e. create a session, redirect, login class. But if sticking with plain functions (procedural) make sure your create a clean separation for each script. So in a nutshell:

- Don't repeat yourself, for example why have both $_SESSION['redirect'] and $_SESSION['url'] these are the same value?
- Don't redirect to a redirect (one script should handle this)
- Separate your concerns - Have a login script doing the login process and a authentication / acl script securing your actual pages (don't combine the two).

Hope the above makes sense, but let me know if not.

Comment: In addition are you sure you haven't protected a page that shouldn't be protected - namely your actual login or index page?

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for your work on this. The login system/script is essentially one that I downloaded from [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/php-login-redirect/), with a few tweaks. The apostrophes weren't included with the variables. Adding them breaks the script. I am fairly new to PHP so it's rather daunting to start building from scratch. That's why I was looking for a ready made solution. Ideally I would just get the script working as is, and then start to address the issues you raise one by one.  I have included config.php and functions.php in full in case that is helpful.

Comment: @Nick not a problem, and I appreciate your dilemma. I had a look at that script you got and I'm afraid to say it is a pile of junk. Unfortunately if you continue using this script you will leave yourself open to so many security flaws it's unbelievable, I think the only positive reviews must have been from the coder himself. Sorry I know this doesn't help you, but you should be aware of this as it could be 'redirect loop problem' today....'site hacked, db destroyed, malware distributed, site banned from google' tomorrow, seems extreme (but that's what could happen). There is simply too..

Comment: many things wrong with that script to know where to start (economically speaking). Did you try replace the $_SESSION[redirect] with $_SESSION['url'] at the top of your check_login.php script? Also have you made sure you didn't put the page protection snippet on the index.php or login.php page (as this would create problems). Lastly thanks for posting other code - but this just raises more eye brows and doesn't seem connected with your problem. One other thing which would help would be do you know the page(s) the user was trying to reach that triggers the loop / did they use the 'remember me'?

Comment: Also I think that script is way OTT for what you probably require - causing needless complications (as you can tell I'm not a fan of it :) I don't mean to direct this at you, just annoys me when I see false claims from people's scripts. Perhaps you could start off with a more simple script, have a look at this for more ideas: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: Thanks for the info/advice. One difficulty I have is that I am not able to reproduce the issue with redirects myself (or only very sporadically), so it's hard to test.  As I'm protecting the whole site (it's essentially a private site for friends), the page protection snippet is on index.php and all other viewable pages (except login.php).  I will make the changes you suggest to check_login.php and ask someone who is experiencing the issue to see if it helps, though it may take a while for feedback, unless you want to have a go at signing up to the site to see how you get on?

Comment: Also I imagine the loop is created trying to access the index.php page

Comment: Hi Nick, it sounds like the problem is basically connected with my other notes - I think the problem is the fact you are trying to protect a page where a redirect is sent to, instead of just letting the user view the page (if authenticated) you are redirecting them to the same page (which in turn goes through your script again - i.e. trys to redirect them). I will add more notes in my original answer (at the top).

Comment: Thanks, I will implement the suggestions at the top of your answer, and will get users to test it.  I will then report back.  I will also have a go at implementing the simpler script you posted the link to on a test site, and seeing if some of the other scripts I have for registration etc and my current database can be integrated with this.  It is frustrating to spend a good deal of time implementing a well reviewed script to find out it's pretty rubbish!  Anyway, thanks again for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: After all your comments about the dodgyness of the script I was using, I decided to invest a few hours yesterday and start from scratch with the script you linked to.  I gradually added the features I need and linked the php to the login/registration forms, and I am pleased to say that all needs to be working well.  I still have to work out the best way to use the 'Remember Me' feature.  I would like to use this if possible, as the site doesn't need to be ultra secure and I'd like to make the site (which is for friends) as user friendly as possible.

Comment: At the moment I am setting a cookie, just for username, and then including `if (!isset($lr_user) && !isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){header("location:/login/login.php");}` at the top of each page to check for the lack of either a username cookie or session username, and redirecting to the login script if not.  Perhaps not the best method, but is OK for now.  I will probably post another question about this in time, and will link to it here when I do.  Thanks again for getting me on the right track.

Comment: @Nick, i'm glad you got things on the right track now (and pleased you decided not to use that script). I agree it is frustrating regarding other people's scripts (when they go wrong), but look at it this way it has been a good learning experience for you and hopefully you have increased you knowledge in certain areas (so not all bad perhaps?). Yes I was wondering if you still wanted the 'remember me'. I would still say it's better to use a 'user_id' rather than username, but like you said please feel free to create another question (and link to this one - so I can track it). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with this code, I think here is the answer:

For users who have disabled cookies (private browsing), all of your users will stuck because of the lines in **check_login.php**. Because these values will be never set and will fall into a loop of **check_login.php** -> **login.php** -> **check_login.php**:

```
$lr_user = $_COOKIE['lr_user']; 
$lr_pass = $_COOKIE['lr_pass']; 

//check to see if cookies have been set previously 
if(($lr_user != "") && ($lr_pass != "")) 
{     
header("Location:/login/redirect.php");     
exit; 
}

//if neither is true, redirect to login        
header("Location:/login/login.php");
```

Bur I really recommend you to go with some [readily available](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/EckoSession/revision/9386) session management snippets.

The problems I see with a quick look that:

a) As Steve says, you MUST not save the username and password in cookies
   EVER. You only save a random session id value.

```
setcookie("lr_user", $username, $duration, "/", $domain); 
setcookie("lr_pass", $password, $duration, "/", $domain);
```

b) Your **functions.php** is subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE username = '$username' and 
password = password('$password')";
```

c) User inputs are never escaped.

```
$username = $_POST[username];                 
$password = $_POST[password];
```

d) You splitted your session management checks all over the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  As I put in the comment under Steve's answer, I will look into other scripts or making the changes suggested, but am just trying to get it working for now.  It's not sensitive data I am protecting, just a website for friends, so I'm not too worried about the security for now, though will institute recommended changes as soon as possible.  I'm not sure about the private browsing issue though.  The feedback I have had is that when 'private browsing' is enabled the redirect issue is resolved.

Comment: @Nick Could you post the content of your /login/login.php as well?